# What is the logical explanation of completeness of a statistic?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

What is the logical explanation of completeness? When the estimator is sufficient we are reducing dimensions as much as possible without losing any information. How is it becoming UMVUE if the statistic is complete as well as sufficient?